# How to dynamically change the number of labels in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Using this tutorial (http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5), I understand how to parse and display contents in JSON to a label.  However, the example has a set number of labels.

How would I dynamically change the number of labels displayed based on the number of contents in the JSON?  The user would scroll down for each label.  In the example from that link, there would be 20 different labels for the 20 different loans.

http://api.kivaws.org/v1/loans/search.json?status=fundraising

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create `UILabel` objects dynamically, and add them to the view where you need them. It should be a `UIScrollView`. Here is a [question and answer that discuss this approach in depth](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10434059/335858).

However, this is not the best approach that you can take, because as the number of labels grows, you start to run out of resources. This slows down your scrolling, among other things, and increases the possibility of running out of memory.

The idiomatic iOS solution to a situation when you need a list of labels that grows dynamically is to use `UITableView`. This class solves the potential resource issues by reusing the cells as they get scrolled off the screen. Although it is possible for you to implement a similar approach with your own scroll view, it would take you considerable effort, but would not look "native" to the users of your application.

Comment: In the example URL, there is only a label.  However, I would like to include other elements for each item in the array (I'm going to be using another JSON feed, this is just the example I'm learning from).  Within that JSON, there will be images as well.  Can I use the UITableView if I have multiple elements that will be inside each cell (different types of text, different images)?

Comment: @sharataka "Can I use the UITableView if I have multiple elements that will be inside each cell" Absolutely! `UITableViewCell` is very versatile, letting you display pretty much anything you want: images, text, etc. The standard styles use at most one image, a large title, and a subtitle, but you can always build your own implementation, with the elements that you need to present the data to the user.